# weird where clasue in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In the code snippet below I see a column in a where clause that I have never seen or used before. The code works and is not my code. My question is if this is some kind of "customized" TSQL language or if is legitimate to have a column in a where clause and if so what is the scope of it.

For example this clause " `WHERE FMTREFl  :vall`" why the :val1?

```
SELECT 1
    ,FMTTRANTYPE
    ,FMTSTATUS
    ,FMTTIMEDATE
    ,FMTREF2
    ,FMTREF3
    ,FMTSEQNO
FROM FMTRANS
WHERE FMTREFl  :vall
    OR FMTHDR  ANY (
        SELECT FMTHSEQNO
        FROM FMTRANSHDR
        WHERE FMTHICPNO :val2
        )

UNION ALL

SELECT 0
    ,FMTTRANTYPE
    ,FMTSTATUS
    ,FMTTIMEDATE
    ,FMTREF2
    ,FMTREF3
    ,FMTSEQNO
FROM FMTRANSIN
WHERE FMTREFl :val3
    OR FMTHDR  ANY (
        SELECT FMTHSEQNO
        FROM FMTRANSHDR
        WHERE FMTHICPNO  :val4
        )
ORDER BY FMTTIMEDATE ASC
```

Comment: You don't tell us what part of the`WHERE` you are unsure on here.

Comment: apologies, I will amend the question

Comment: Where does this code "work"? I am thinking there must be some kind of pre-compiler attached or something.

Comment: Is this from a code where this query is wrapped in a piece of code which effectively replaces those parts with the operator and the value to be used for the comparison? Some kind of homebrew ORM maybe? How do you use this query exactly? What and how is running it on the SQL Server?

Comment: The subquery clauses aren't valid either. The `ANY` keyword needs to be preceded by a comparison operator.

Comment: Hi Thomas, surely not in SQL server; I work for a company that has a software vendor that uses "proprietary code"; I wanted just to be sure by asking the question that this is not TSQL or PL/SQL. And I do not use the query; is a long story, I should explain the nature of my work :-)

Comment: Yes you should explain, as so far we don't have valid code. Possibly valid in SQlite? Not sure